# Restore Standby database failed in Oracle 11g express

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have two machine **A** and **B** and i want two setup standby database in machine B, so i have followed below steps..

1. Install **oracle 11g express** in machine A and same install in another
   machine B for standby.
2. Enable Archive mode in both machine A and B.
3. Create TableSpace with name **tbs_test** on both machine.
4. Create user **testuser** on both machine & grant permission for dba.
5. In Machine A, i have create a table **Tb_Employee** and insert data
   into table **Tb_Employee** on table space **tbs_test**.
6. Now take backup from some script on machine **A** and trying to
   restore on machine **B** but not succeed due to some error mentioned in below statement.

> SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE;
>
> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE
>
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
>
> ORA-19909: datafile 1 belongs to an orphan incarnation
>
> ORA-01110: data file 1: 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF'

*I have used following script to take backup(Full backup + Archive)*

**Step 1 Execute Begin Backup Script**

> conn / as sysdba;
> alter system checkpoint;
>
> alter tablespace SYSAUX begin backup;
>
> alter tablespace SYSTEM begin backup;
>
> alter tablespace TBS_Test begin backup;
>
> exit;

**Step 2 Copy SYSAUX.DBF, SYSTEM.DBF and TBS_Test.DBF files to backup directory**

**Step 3 create standby control file through execute following script**

> conn / as sysdba;
>
> alter database backup controlfile to trace as 'C:\Backup\controlfile.txt'  reuse;
>
> alter database backup controlfile to 'C:\Backup\controlfile.ctl' reuse;
>
> alter database create standby controlfile as 'C:\Backup\controlfile_standby.ctl';
>
> exit

**Step 4 copy stand by control file as Control.DBF into backup directory**

**Step 5 After copied files Execute End Backup Script**

> conn / as sysdba;
>
> alter tablespace SYSAUX end backup;
>
> alter tablespace SYSTEM end backup;
>
> alter tablespace UNDOTBS1 end backup;
>
> alter tablespace TBS_Test end backup;
>
> exit;

**Step 6 Execute script for Archive log**

> conn / as sysdba;
>
> alter system checkpoint;
>
> alter system archive log current;
>
> disconnect;
>
> exit;

**Step 7 After execute script copy all archive files into backup directory("C:/Backup")**

After just restore file into Machine B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not sure Oracle Express support standby (please consult the
   documentation - as I remember Data Guard is licensed on top of
   Enterprize Edition)
2. In order to configure standby it is not enough just to backup one
   instance and restore to another - for this you will have to make
   some more configurations (for example - to name instances according,
   FORCE LOGGING, backup controlfile for standby, set LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST
   parameters and many others, see documentation)

Your question is too "wide" we don't know what and how it has been done (put the scripts here), and in which order.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Please check here oracle express support data guard standby [check here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC116). for script i have edit my question again please check.

Comment: In the link you posted it is said: "Options and Major Features Not Included" - <Oracle Data Guard-Redo Apply> so you can not apply archivelogs in your XE standby. Check please this also https://community.oracle.com/thread/416528

Comment: You can find info about how to set-up standby here ->  http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SBYDB/toc.htm

Comment: How can i restore only archive backup in oracle express 11g?

Comment: looks like you mix the terms - "backup" is one thing "archives" is another - what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want move archives logs between primary server to standby server every after 15 min.

Comment: You can't create a standby on XE edition, but in general (not XE) you must configure the LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_N = 'SERVICE=YOUR_SRE_NAME' parameter in order that oracle to send archivelog to standby